# Drupal AJAX won't work on Google Chrome on Android smartphones

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal

On desktops works fine, on smartphones too - except for Google Chrome on Android devices. When I use Chrome's Device Inspector it shows that the AJAX request takes too long to respond, when it's done it returns incomplete results.

What could be the reason? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome is timing out before the site returns results, therefore the solution is basically: "get there faster". [Make sure the site's caching is enabled and working properly](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/performance), and that you have sufficient server resources to deliver the content in a reasonable amount of time. If the request is particularly long or complex try to provide it in smaller pieces across multiple requests that you can complete more quickly (note this may cause a slower overall experience but avoid the timeout). Keep in mind that mobile devices frequently operate on slower connections and so you need to take that into account when dealing with speed issues.